How to get all possible AppServicePlan configurations from an Azure subscription?
I want to get a List with all possible AppService Hosting Plan configuration settings of my Azure subscription(Location, Tier, Size,...). Possibly through skus.

It should be done using Azure SDK for .NET.
Environment is .Net 8.0 Console Application(Windows)
I already have a SubscriptionResource object to work with. Every sample and code here will assume "subscription" variable to be that object.
Essentially, I want to get this data:

Here is an example of code and how the output is expected:

        var skus = await AppServiceExtensions.GetSkusAsync(subscription);

        if (hostingPlanSkus != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Available App Service SKUs:");
            foreach (var sku in hostingPlanSkus)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Tier: {sku.Tier}, Name: {sku.Name}, Size: {sku.Size}, Family: {sku.Family}");
            }
        }

Available App Service SKUs:
Tier: Free, Name: Free, Size: F1, Family: F
Tier: Basic, Name: Basic1, Size: B1, Family: B
Tier: Standard, Name: Standard1, Size: S1, Family: S
Tier: PremiumV2, Name: PremiumV2_1, Size: P1v2, Family: Pv2

What have I tried?

Using GetSkusAsync() returns null every-time. I've tried with different subscriptions and result is the same.

var skus = await AppServiceExtensions.GetSkusAsync(subscription);
foreach (var sku in skus.Value.Skus)
{
        Console.WriteLine($"- Tier: {sku.Tier}, Size: {sku.Size}, Name: {sku.Name}");
}


I thought maybe was that the SubscriptionResource could not just get the hosting plan configuration plans like in Azure portal because the SubscriptionResource is used to create,store,modify already the resources. So I looked to try with MockableAppServiceSubscriptionResource. But I could't get an object out of it that would make me be able to call the function in the first try(GetSkusAsync).

If you know how to get possible hosting plan configuration. Please do share your knowledge. And if it not currently possible with Azure sdk for .net, I would also appreciate the info.
Thank you and best regards,

Are you getting any error with the above code?

No error. Just not the expected value.

I am able to get the App Service Plan Configurations with the below code.

I have used Tenant and Subscription ID to make sure the request is issued for correct Azure AD.

using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {       
        string TId = "**********";
        string SubID = "**********";

        var cred = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = TId
        });

        var ARMC = new ArmClient(cred);

        var sub = ARMC.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{SubID}"));
        Console.WriteLine("App Service Plan Details:");

        await foreach (var asp in sub.GetAppServicePlansAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {asp.Data.Name}");           
            Console.WriteLine($"Tier: {asp.Data.Sku.Tier}, Name: {asp.Data.Sku.Name}, Size: {asp.Data.Sku.Size}, Family: {asp.Data.Sku.Family}");

            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));
        }
    }
}

My .csproj file:
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.13.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.AppService" Version="1.3.0" />

Output:

As an alternative option you can use Azure CLI to get the details. Refer this SOThread once.

What you are getting with your code is a list of already created hosting plans on your subscription. What I want is a list of possible hosting plan configuration. What do I mean by "possible hosting plan configuration" ? When creating a app service plan in Azure Portal, you can select different pricing plans, they all have different configurations. You see something like "Free F1 60 minutes/day compute N/A 1 1 N/A N/A Free Free" for the free option. I want to be able to request that plan selection information from Azure. Why? Maybe they change that info in the future.

Ok..will check once again and let you know.

Thanks, I appreciate the effort! I fixed my question to be more clear, I'm not too used to creating posts here so forgive me for not being to clear in the question.

Can you check this RestAPI once

AFAIK, using Azure CLI we can get details of a particular region or for a particular subscription.az appservice plan list --query "[].sku" --out table . Using this command I am able to see only for available app services.For detailed pricing check Pricing Calculator

I can see the Rest API to get the list of SKU, but unable to retrieve the value(getting null)

I appreciate the info. All those options are valid ones to get the hosting pricing info. Unfortunately my goal was to code only using azure-sdk-for-.net.

Try to use the RestAPI in the code and get the details.
